# Line highlighting in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I highlight a line in paragraph with javascript. Background color of line should change when line is over it. A single should should highlight for it's starting to full stop. And please provide code in javascript not jquery.

Comment: Do you want it giftwrapped?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in CSS. Wrap all your lines in a 'span' with a class (for instance 'highlight'):

```
<span class="highlight">line 1</span>
<span class="highlight">line 2</span>
```

and so on. Then use CSS to give the lines a different background color on hover:

```
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a event listener here, to do this your can use mouseover and mouseout, mouseover is when the mouse is over an object and mouse out is when the mouse the out of an object. You can understand this by below example:

```js
const yourTextName = document.getElementById('your-text-id');

yourTextName.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
    yourTextName.style.backgroundColor="yellow"
})

yourTextName.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=>{
    yourTextName.style.backgroundColor="white"
})
```

```css
#your-text-id{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>codedamn HTML Playground</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="your-text-id">Your Text</h1>
        <script src="/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```